# Working with Electrodermal data from Empatica E4 - how to plot with time?

Tags: python, pandas, biometrics

I'm working with electrodermal data imported from an Empatica E4. I want to create descriptives and z score the data then plot it. I've managed to get so far with the 
below:

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
# Download data
df = pd.read_csv("EDA.csv")
# Plot it
df.plot()

import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import zscore
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('EDA.csv', sep=','))
print(df.describe())
df = df.apply(zscore) # Normalization
print(df.describe())
print (df)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df)
```

Here's my output:

[Descriptives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhjKl.png)
[Z SCORE plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02yvu.png)

I want to change the x axis so that it reads time rather than the data point number. What stuck on is how to read in EDA.csv data at its 4hz sample rate and include that in my plot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `plt.plot(df.set_index('your_column_time'))`?

Comment: Time isn't in a separate column. The data is read at 4hz so each data point is .25 seconds apart. What I need to work out is how to interpret time sequence data that is encoded in Hz

Comment: so 1 second is 4 points .... so divide the column of number of points by 4 and it will be in seconds